# Is ATMEGA328P the same as 16U2?

Tags: arduino-mega

I've been playing with my Arduino for a few months.

But, I just bought a shield that says it needs to be used with ATMEGA328P.  My box says I have a 328P, however, reading the chip, it's inscribed with "ATMEL MEGA16U2".

Does that mean the box is wrong, or is that the same as 328P somehow?

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you post a picture of your board?

Answer (score 4):

The 16u2 is related to the ATmega328p, and includes USB, but is more limited in resources.   While it would be *possible* to make an Arduino-type board from alone, this is unlikely to be what you have.

Rather, it is likely that you have a board with an ATmega328p as the main processor, and *also* a 16u2 which serves as a USB interface for it.

You could know for sure from what board type you select in the dropdown menu of the Arduino IDE.  If you are selecting something like "Uno" or "Duemilanove" you have a 328p as the main processor.

(The other presently common type of board is the "Leonardo" style where a 32u4 - essentially a bigger version of the 16u2 - is used as a single-chip solution that is both the primary processor and the USB interface.  But if that is what you had, it would not say 16u2 on it, unless it was an attempt to make a more limited "budget" version).

Comment: You are correct - when I plug it in and use the IDE, I can connect to it as an Uno.  Thank you, @Chris Stratton!

Answer (score 3):

the 328p is the microcontoller. It's the larger chip located in the middle of the arduino board surface. This one handles the code/ sketch/ programme that you write). The 16u2, on the other hand, is the smaller chip located near the USB port. This handles data communication through the USB port.